# Generate unique number within range based on given number or string

Tags: java, algorithm, random, sampling

What I am trying to achieve is some thing like this, Say we have a list of one thousand boxes and a list of 25 colors, now we want to assign colors to boxes such that the color is from given list, and every time i ask the box for color the same color will be choosen. The same color can be used by multiple boxes but the color of a same box will always be same no matter how many time I execute the algorithm.

I think I can have a list of 25 colors and an algorithm to create a unique number (within range of 25) based on name or id of the box.

Can any one help me what algorithm should work for me ?

**update**
The requirement has changed slightly, and now I need five unique colors from that range, and the colors has to be same always. Say we are arranging boxes in groups of five, each box should get unique color within the range of 25 colors. And algorithm should give same colors for same group always.

Answer (score 4):

```
box.getId().hashCode() % 25
```

will get you a number between 0 and 24 (inclusive).

Note that since you didn't specify any rule for the distribution of the colors among boxes, the following algorithm also satisfies your requirements:

```
return 0;
```

If you want a good distribution, then iterate through your boxes, and fill a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the box id and the value is the color:

```
Map<String, Integer> colorsByBoxId = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int i = 0;
for (Box box : boxes) {
    int colorIndex = i % 25;
    i++;
    colorsByBoxId.put(box.getId(), colorIndex);
}
```

And then use this map each time you want to get the color of a box.

Or simply do the same, and add a `color` field to the Box class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Obviously I want good distribution, expect all 25 colors to be used. Its not feasible to create the Map as you suggested, as we cant keep thousands of objects loaded in memory

Comment: You have a list of one thousand boxes. That would lead to a tiny map, holding only a few KBs in memory. But if that's too much, then make sure your IDs are well distributed, and use the hashCode of the ID.

Comment: That was just an example of the problem I am trying to solve, but in reality, its not box, its some other entities and we have thousands of records. Yes I think db id % 25 should work as well, isnt it ?

Comment: If the ID is a sequence number, incremented by 1 each time a new box is created, you'll have a perfect distribution. If it's a number incremented by 25 each time a new box is created, then the distribution will suck, because the modulo will always return the same value. If it's a random UUID, you can hope for a good distribution. But why don't you assign a random color to the box each time it's created and stored in the database?

Comment: Ids are incremented by one - yeah storing the color shouldnt be a problem as well.

Comment: JB Nizet - Well the requirement has changed slightly, and now I need five uniuqe colors from that range, and the colors has to be same always. Say we are arranging boxes in groups of five, each box should get unique color within the range of 25 colors. And alogorithm should give same colors for same group always.

Comment: As I said: assign random colors at creation time. Shuffle an array of 25 colors, and take the 5 first ones. See `Collections.shuffle()`.